# Solution to insert cross-hyperlinks of Rails objects inside text attribute (as HTML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, ckeditor, hyperlink

I am working at a web app in Rails that behaves much like a CMS: there are articles, which have a text attribute that contains links to other articles (or other object classes). I'm currently storing the attribute as HTML.

Is there any good way to model those links in a way that is relative easy to change, and contain the reference to the object id, instead of the absolute url?

**One of the solutons** I was thinking was to use some kind of special mark-up, such as:

```
[link_to "Text for the link", Article:12]
```

where 12 is the id of the article it links to. This mark-up will be parsed when the text is rendered.

The downside of this is that I have to hack into TinyMCE (the editor I'm thinking of using to edit the HTML) so that it can insert links to other objects, by accessing the database and automatically assigning the object type and ID (the person who's editing the texts doesn't know the id's).

**Is there any simple solution to this?**

Or should I stick to using absolute urls (which, besides maintenance issues, is annoying in development, as they will always point to production and that is confusing for me)?

Additionally, does anyone have similar examples in other languages (php, Wordpress, other CMS, etc) that tackle this problem in a nice way? I'm thinking, this is pretty vital in CMS, and can reduce a lot of man hours if a nice system can handle all those links.

**EDIT:**

Another possible solution that I'm thinking about is letting the person copy the link of the article directly in the code, but it should, upon submission, generate the correct association id and make it so that if the url structure changes, the link is always up-to-date. I'd like to hear your opinions and experience with this approach, if you have tried it.

The challenge with this approach is parsing the link with Rails and finding out that it points to an Article, and that article has the id `##`. Then I have to insert a shortcode that will always translate, upon parsing and rendering, to an actual link to that article.

I found a method that could make this feasible:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path
```

But there may be some caveats that I don't see right now...

**EDIT no. 2**

I also want to specify that I chose [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) as the content editor, but I will consider other ones if there are clearer advantages.

Comment: I have done something similar using your first solution. It's similar to the way shortcodes in systems like wordpress operate. I then built a helper that would parse any text possibly containing the shortcodes and call a relevant method on the model. e.g: `parse_article_desc(article)` where we can then perform methods on the model as opposed to only the text. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built something similar using a shortcode system which would allow me to call specific methods on the model and replace the shortcode in the text:

#### Helper

```
def parse_shortcode(model)
  text = model.text      
  text.gsub(/(\[#!\s?\w+\])/i) do |match|
    result = model.try(match)
    result.nil? '' : link_to(result[:text], result[:url])
  end
end
```

#### Model

```
def contact_link
  { :text => self.name, :url => self.url }
end
```

#### View

```
<%= parse_shortcode(@article) %>
```

I haven't tested the above code and it is obviously a bit simplified but it explains my thought process behind this.

EDIT: Just to clarify my above example uses an invented shortcode syntax of `[#! method]`

Comment: This is useful, when I will parse the content for the shortcodes, which I will have to end up using, because of their flexibility. I'm not sure though I want to expose every method of the model, but I could whitelist methods easily. This said, a combination of your answer and @James Mason's answer will be suitable for acceptance...

Comment: As you say... You could always do something like `shortcode_#{match}` so that you have complete control over the accessible methods. Glad to have helped.

Comment: Nice... that's a cool trick :) I would have created a symbol list and a custom method that only calls the methods in that list. But that's crazy compared to your nice simple solution :D

Answer (score 2):

An article can have many related_articles and at the same time this article can be related by many other articles, so it is best to model this as a many-to-many relationship.

One way to define this type of relationship in Rails is `has_many :through`.

To use `has_many :through` you have to create a join model, perhaps call it **ArticleRelation**. This model will have two fields, an *article_id* that represents the current article and a *related_article_id* that represents the article who’s being referred as related.

```
class Article < AR::Base
  has_many :article_relations
  has_many :related_articles, :through => :article_relations
end

class ArticleRelation < AR::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :article_relation, :class_name => 'Article'
end
```

When creating self-referential relationships it’s important to remember that you’re only creating one side of the relationship. Although **article_1** might list **article_2** as related, there is no way to for **article_2** to list **article_1** as related. You'd need two **ArticleRelation** records to create a mutual relationship.

It’s difficult to think up appropriate names to define another side of the relationship so you can prefix both with the word “inverse” to give **inverse_article_relations** and **inverse_related_articles**. You also need to specify some additional options to make the relationships work. For **inverse_article_relations** you’ll have to specify the name of the other model as it can’t be inferred from the relationship name and you’ll also have to define the foreign key as **related_article_id**. For the **inverse_related_articles** relationship you need to specify the source as **articles**, as again it cannot be inferred from the name of the relationship.

```
has_many :inverse_article_relations, :class_name => "ArticleRelation", :foreign_key => "related_article_id"
has_many :inverse_related_articles, :through => :inverse_article_relations, :source => :article
```

Test it out, this should work for you per current requirement.

Comment: I already have a many-to-many relationship, so I know that an Article is linking to n other articles. However, I want to find an easy way to create the links in the editor, so it's easy both for the person who is creating the links, but is also a pragmatical approach in the code. I'm currently using CKEditor (latest version) but I have yet to experiment with custom actions (such as picking another article & generating the link).

Answer (score 1):

A solution I've seen in a lot of other CMSs is a combination of custom file browser in TinyMCE and page rewriting (similar to freakyDaz's answer).

TinyMCE has [documentation and example code](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3afile_browser_callback) for implementing a custom browser. You'll have to provide the backend pieces, of course.

CKEditor has [documentation for a similar feature](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29/Custom_File_Browser) as well.

Have your backend implementation return something that's easy to parse for the URLs (urlfor:Article:12, for instance), then have your rendering code replace those with actual URLs.

Comment: Interesting...  I'm currently using CKEditor (latest version) but I have yet to experiment with custom actions (such as picking another article & generating the link). I hope there is an equivalent for CKEditor to the example from your link.

Comment: Updated with a link to the CKEditor docs for a custom file browser.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of another possible solution for the use case:

1. The admin user specifies the relationships before they edit the text (using [Chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), this can be done in a user-friendly way).
2. Then the person either submits the form to save the model or it can be done asynchronously.
3. When the relationships are saved, a shortcode is generated and displayed for each of them, and that short-code can easily be pasted in the text.
4. When displaying the text in the front-end, the text will be parsed for the shortcode, in a similar way to what [@freakyDaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14219816/322253) is suggesting.

In this way, I don't have to hack or create custom actions in the editor. I think it's a pretty pragmatical approach, but I'd like to hear your opinions. Of course, the admin who's making the text should be educated to follow the process in that order, but in my case very few persons can be admins (1 or 2), so it's manageable.

Comment: If your valid relationships can be constrained that tightly, I don't see why it wouldn't work. It sounds like it would be more work for the admins, but it should be a lot easier for the users (since they can't pick an invalid relationship).